# Can I test tvOS apps on the AppleTV?

Tags: tvos

I'm aware the deadline for the developer kit for AppleTV has now passed some time ago.

What I'm confused by is, is it not possible to test tvOS apps on the actual AppleTV itself?

Is it possible to say hook up your mac with the tv device via HDMI and test it that way, like the way you do with other apps?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a video showing how to test an app in Apple TV with TestFlight. https://youtu.be/Bsgdnl3dd4U .

1. Install TestFlight in your Apple TV first
2. Use "redeem code" to be able to see the apps in your TestFlight
3. Afterwards, you can see your beta versions on TestFlight.

Answer (score 3):

The dev kit is an actual AppleTV and was recently updated to the official tvOS release. You can test tvOS apps on it (or any other AppleTV) by connecting it to your Mac with a USB-C cable.

Comment: Many thanks, but the latest MBP doesn't have USB-C if I remember. I might be wrong. Would I need a Lightning to USB Cable or USB-A to USB-C Cable?

Comment: You need a USB-A (or whatever is on your computer) to USB-C (which is on the AppleTV) cable.

Comment: Is there any other way to connect the Apple TV to the Mac in order to test the app? Or is USB-C to USB-A the only way?

Comment: How about wireless testing using Xcode 9?  Is there a way to install via wireless like you can with phones/tablets?

Comment: The latest AppleTV's don't have a usb port. See my answer to run over the wifi network.

Answer (score 2):

To run your tvOS app on an AppleTV on your local wifi network:

1. On your AppleTV go to Settings > Remotes and Devices > Remote App and Devices.
2. In Xcode open Window > Devices and Simulators. You should see your AppleTV listed there.
3. Press the 'Pair' button and fill the 6 digit code shown on the tv.